# Стоит ли размещать сервер в офисе?

Tags: сервер

есть корпоративный мессенджер, примерные задачи:

- Количество пользователей ≈ 10000 человек
- Возможность обмена как файлами данных (csv, excel, docx, txt и т.п.)
- Возможность обмена видео и аудио записями, а также (что важно!) возможность обмена фотографиями без урезки качества, то есть есть full hd или ultra hd фотография, так и должна сохраняться

Посоветуйте, стоит ли ставить сервер для такого мессенджера в офисе, а если да, сколько памяти на такую задачу может потребоваться и какие составляющие для сервера выбрать

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-365/business/compare-all-microsoft-365-business-products?market=ru

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю это должен быть общедоступный сервер. Если вы его хотите разместить физически в своем офисе то вам нужно убедится в наличии белого IP-шника.
Во вторых вам нужна хорошая скорость соединения так-как это будет хороший объем данных. Дальше нужно разобраться будет ли это "транспортный" сервер, либо сервер с сохранением данных. И ещё такие детали как безперебойное питание сервера, роутера и при наличии свича. Для "транспортника" не нужен большой проц. 4-6 ядер с 2.1-2.2ггЦ хватит. Оперативки побольше, 64 минимум, а лучше 120+ и обезательно ECC. А объем накоптелей это уже математика, исходя из задачи и количества. Так-же нужно разобратся в RAID масивах, нужны ли они вам или нет. При большем объеме их нужно ставить!